# Allocated memory continously increasing in Android ? How to track which object is being stored while using an external library

Tags: android, performance

I am using Shimmer library for Android (Provided by Facebook), after starting shimmer animation,
if we look at the memory monitor, the allocated memory keeps on increasing at a steady rate i.e. .05MB/sec or so.

How can I track which object in the class is being stored and taking so much memory ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concern yourself with increasing memory usage. The problem is, if it throws `Out Of Memory` exception. This can happen because of memory leaks. To detect memory leaks, you can use an excellent library called [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).